# Multinomial logistic regression steps in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have data suited to multinomial logistic regression but I don't know how to formulate the model in predicting my Y.

- How do I perform Multinomial Logistic Regression using SPSS?
- How does stepwise method work?

Comment: This is not a statistics question; it's a software question.  Have you read the SPSS Help files or found your way into the Tutorial?  Often times, to reach a specialized topic, you need to look in its Help files until you find a link that says Show Me.  That will take you to a part of the Tutorial not accessible via the main Tutorial menu.  If that doesn't help, you can try posting the question on the SPSS listserv.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples of annotated output for SPSS multinomial logistic regression:

- [UCLA example](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/output/mlogit.htm)
- [My own list of links and resources](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/multinomial-logistic-regression-spss.html)

Stepwise method provides a data driven approach to selection of your predictor variables. In general the decision to use data-driven or direct entry or hierarchical approaches is related to whether you want to test theory (i.e., direct entry or hierarchical) or you want to simply optimise prediction (i.e., stepwise and related methods).